# High ram load and "Error creating window handle" exception

Tags: c#, garbage-collection, windows-services, window-handles

in my c# windows service I get an exception, Error creating window handle.
I'm working on a sip program. for each call 263KB ram used and after 1.2GB usage of ram I get above error. Handles are about 1300 on my service. My machine has enough free memory. I do dispose on every object I create.

how can I trace that and find the problem?

Comment: That was because of timers created but didn't release even by using stop and dispose methods ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That was because of timers created but didn't release even by using stop and dispose methods ...

Answer (score 0):

If you use Visual Studio Professional or Enterprise, you can see it in Memory Usage. It will be show on current snapshot. Maybe you have a infinity loop or incorrect dispose.

Comment: That is a windows service.how to attach debugger?

Comment: You can use remote debugger and you can connect to service via your visual studio.